# ngx-datatable only binds to last comparator

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

When using `ngx-datatable-column` templates and binding comparator functions, only the last binded comparator for all sortable columns.

For example:

```
<div class="m-333">
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="openPopUp({}, true)">Add User</button>
</div>

<mat-card class="p-0" [@animate]="{value:'*',params:{y:'50px',delay:'300ms'}}">
  <mat-card-content class="p-0">
    <ngx-datatable #ngxDatatable class="material ml-0 mr-0" [rows]="rows" [columnMode]="'force'" [headerHeight]="50"
      [footerHeight]="50" [scrollbarH]="true" [rowHeight]="50" [externalPaging]="false" [count]="page.count"
      [sortType]="'multi'" [offset]="page.offset" [limit]="page.size" (page)='setPage($event)'>
      <ngx-datatable-column name="Name" prop="displayName" [flexGrow]="1" [sortable]="false" [comparator]="displayNameComparator">
        <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
          {{ row?.displayName }}
        </ng-template>
      </ngx-datatable-column>
      <ngx-datatable-column name="Email" prop="email" [flexGrow]="1" [sortable]="false" [comparator]="emailComparator">
        <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
          {{ row?.email }}
        </ng-template>
      </ngx-datatable-column>
      <ngx-datatable-column name="Creation Date" prop="creationTime" [flexGrow]="1" [sortable]="true"
        [comparator]="creationDateComparator">
        <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
          {{ row?.metadata.creationTime | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm' }}
        </ng-template>
      </ngx-datatable-column>
      <ngx-datatable-column name="Last Sign" [flexGrow]="1">
        <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
          {{ row?.metadata.lastSignInTime | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm' }}
        </ng-template>
      </ngx-datatable-column>
      <!-- <ngx-datatable-column name="Status" [flexGrow]="1">
        <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
          <mat-chip mat-sm-chip [color]="'warn'" [selected]="isRowActive(row)">
            {{isRowActive(row) ? 'Active' : 'Complete'}}</mat-chip>
        </ng-template>
      </ngx-datatable-column> -->
      <ngx-datatable-column name="Actions" [flexGrow]="1">
        <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
          <button mat-icon-button mat-sm-button color="primary" class="mr-1" (click)="openPopUp(row, false)">
            <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
          </button>
          <button mat-icon-button mat-sm-button color="warn" (click)="deleteItem(row)">
            <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
          </button>
        </ng-template>
      </ngx-datatable-column>
      <ngx-datatable-footer>
        <ng-template ngx-datatable-footer-template let-rowCount="rowCount" let-pageSize="pageSize"
          let-selectedCount="selectedCount" let-curPage="curPage" let-offset="offset" let-isVisible="isVisible">
          <div class="page-count">
            Total: {{rowCount.toLocaleString()}}
          </div>
          <datatable-pager [pagerLeftArrowIcon]="'datatable-icon-left'" [pagerRightArrowIcon]="'datatable-icon-right'"
            [pagerPreviousIcon]="null" [pagerNextIcon]="null" [page]="curPage" [size]="pageSize" [count]="rowCount"
            [hidden]="!((rowCount / pageSize) > 1)" (change)='setPage($event)'>
          </datatable-pager>
        </ng-template>
      </ngx-datatable-footer>
    </ngx-datatable>
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

The `creationDateComparator` will be called for the first column, "Name", second column, "Email" and of course for the 3rd column, "Creation Date", as it is the last binded comparator.

I can tell whatever column I sort first binds that comparator function to all columns. So if I choose to sort the Email column first, than I when I call the Name column it uses the emailComparator but also the email values not the displayName values.

I am surprised if this expected behavior, should be able to bind a different comparator function for each column...

Comment: Hmm.. What is the expected behaviour of your comparator function?

Comment: I have 3 comparator functions 1 for each column, all 3 functions assist in sorting that columns data. 1 comparator sorts strings, another sorts emails and the final sorts Dates

Answer (score 0):

You are right. Ngx-datable should work with multiple comparator functions. One for each column. It works correctly in both ways by specifying comparator functions in HTML templates and in typescript files.

The issue I see in your code is that you did not set `prop` attribute on any ngx column. Try setting it for each individual column. I think it should work then.

Comment: Not providing a prop value is simply a way to pass an entire row to the comparator. I have tried setting a prop value for each comparator but this does not help.